# OpenCV Template matching against video

Tags: opencv, numpy, threshold, template-matching

Assuming I have a template image and searching for a match in a video,what is the measure to be looked for  ?

From OpenCV tutorial [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html)
1.loc = np.where( res >= threshold) gives me numpy array.How to infer it on a scale of 1-100,where 100 refers to exact match and 80 refers to 80% match and so on.
2.I am not clear on min,max values ..what does rectangle coordinates denote?
  # Apply template Matching
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with Python, but I have worked with template matching and OpenCV.

Performing a template match produces a results matrix - called `res` in your example.

Depending on the template matching method used, the brightest/darkest (max/min) points on this result matrix are your best matches.

In your example the method `cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED` is used which will normalise the result matrix values between 0 and 1.

You can then iterate over your result matrix points and only store those points which pass a certain threshold, in the example they use 0.8 which is equivalent to an 80% match.

The last step involves marking each match onto the drawing by using the rectangle drawing function which works as follows:

```
Rectangle(img, pt1, pt2, color, thickness=1, lineType=8, shift=0)
```

- `img` - image matrix, the picture you want to draw on
- `pt1` - Top left point of the rectangle (x,y)
- `pt2` - Bottom right point of the rectangle (x,y)
- `color` - Line colour (BGR format)

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919094/template-matching-in-opencv-java/31921582#31921582) and provided an example that might be of some help to you too.